# Create a table of subject using html and ruby

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

I try to create a table of subjects when each subject and sub-subject we got them from the database, in case of code ruby every thinks fine, the problem only in view.

I try to make the table :

[image]

But I got this table error in design view :

[image]

I got data from database but when i try to do table using   including 2 boucle! design broken.

My code :

```
    <table class="report-card" dir="rtl" style="table-layout: fixed;page-break-after: avoid !important;width:100%;padding: 0;margin: 0;float:right;">
    
    <tr>    
       <td class= "td-1"><b><%=' المادة'%></b></td>
       <%ordered_groups.each do |g|%>
       <%count = @subjects.select{|subject| subject.group_id == g.id}.count%>
        <% @subjects.select{|sub| sub.group_id == g.id}.sort_by{|s| s.subject_order}.each do |subject| %>
                     <%@v << subject  %>
                    <%end>
      
     <td colspan="<%= count %>" class="td-subject-groups" >
    
     <table>
               <tr>
         <td  class="td-subject-groups"> <%= g.name %></td>
                   
               </tr>           
               <tr>    
    
    <%@v.each do |l|%>        
         <td  class="td-subject-groups"><%= l.name%></td>
         <%end%>
    
    </tr>
       
           </table>
       </td>
    
    
    </tr>
    <%end>
```

Note:

```
g.name => subject
l.name => subsubject 


for each subject, we have multiple sub-subject
```

Comment: Sorry but this code is a train wreck and you have a lot more then the design issues to fix. In that loop you're creating a N+1 query issue since it does an additional count query for each row. Use a counter cache or select a count per group in the controller. Your views should just take data from the controller and render it in the simplest possible way.

Comment: Can you include the full text of your controller, and the code from your models as well please?